# Protractor/Jasmin Stop execution or skip test if BeforeAll or BeforeEach fails

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Is there any way to Stop execution or skip test if there are any failures in BeforeAll or BeforeEach ? in Protractor+Jasmin framework

I have tried few things which are not helping like: protractor-fail-fast, jasmine-bail-fast, topSpecOnExpectationFailure: true

In my test if Login does not work in BeforeAll or BeforeEach Test are still getting executed. 
Is there any why by which if Login fails it skips the execution in it() blocks.

Answer (score 1):

i think there won't be nice solution here. I can suggest some hack like this:

```
describe('Some feature', function () {
    preconditionFailed = false

    beforeAll(async function () {
       try {
          await somePreconditions()
          preconditionFailed = false
       } catch(err) {
          preconditionFailed = true
          throw err
       }
    }

    beforeEach(async function () {
       try {
          await somePreconditions()
          preconditionFailed = false
       } catch(err) {
          preconditionFailed = true
          throw err
       }
    }

    it('should work', async feature() {
        if(preconditionFailed) {
            throw new Error('Precondition failed, cannot start test')
        }
        await someTestLogic()
    })

})
```